# XGBoost: minimize influence of continuous linear features as opposed to categorical

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, data-science, xgboost, feature-selection

Lets say I have 100 independent features - 90 are binary (e.g. 0/1) and 10 are continuous variables (e.g. age, height, weight, etc). I use the 100 features to predict a classifier problem with an adequate amount of samples.

When I set a XGBClassifier function and fit it, then the 10 most important features from the standpoint of `gain` are always the 10 continuous variable. For now I am not interested in `cover` or `frequency`. The 10 continuous variables take up like .8 to .9 of space in `gain` list ( sum(gain) = 1).

I tried tuning the `gamma`, `reg_alpha` , `reg_lambda` , `max_depth`, `colsample`. Still top 10 features by gain are always the 10 continuous features.

Any suggestions?

small update -- someone asked why I think this is happening. I believe it's because a continuous variable can be split on multiple times per decision tree. A binary variable can only be split on once. Hence, the higher prevalence of continuous variables in trees and thus a higher `gain` score

Comment: Yes, a tree will generally 'prefer' continuous variables to binary categorical ones, if splitting on the continuous variables gives more information gain (since the algorithm can choose the continuous split-point). If that's the optimal tree, then it's the optimal tree. When you say "any suggestions", what exactly do you want? To find which of the other 90 binary categorical features give the most information gain? To train a suboptimal tree to find out? To engineer some compound features by combining the binary features into n-bit categorical features which have more information gain?

Comment: Near-duplicate of [Why do Decision Trees/rpart prefer to choose continuous over categorical variables?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171192/decision-trees-rpart-r-categorical-and-continuous-variables)

Comment: I think he wants to reduce the relative "gain" those features produce. which directly conflicts with how this algorithm works. But there are ways to "bend" the algorithm.

Comment: Generally if you have very-low-information variables, tweaking parameters (as opposed to feature engineering) won't help, as long as you used a sensible value of alpha, lambda (although try a few values of eta to make sure your training speed is right). Did you use the defaults `subsample=1, colsample_bytree=1`, or reduce them to 0.6..0.9 to inject a little (seeded) randomness? Was your `eval_metric='error'`as, in binary classification error?

Comment: Oh and was the class distribution roughly 50/50? If not, look into auc or stratified sampling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, **it's well-known that a tree(/forest) algorithm (xgboost/rpart/etc.) will generally 'prefer' continuous variables over binary categorical ones in its variable selection, since it can choose the continuous split-point wherever it wants to maximize the information gain** (and can freely choose different split-points for that same variable at other nodes, or in other trees). If that's the optimal tree (for those particular variables), well then it's the optimal tree. See [Why do Decision Trees/rpart prefer to choose continuous over categorical variables?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171192/decision-trees-rpart-r-categorical-and-continuous-variables) on sister site CrossValidated.

When you say "any suggestions", depends what exactly do you want, it could be one of the following:

- a) To find which of the other 90 binary categorical features give the most information gain
- b) To train a suboptimal tree just to find out which features those are
- c) To engineer some "compound" features by combining the binary features into n-bit categorical features which have more information gain (while being sure to remove the individual binary features from the input)
- d) You could look into **association rules** : [What is the practical difference between association rules and decision trees in data mining?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44977/what-is-the-practical-difference-between-association-rules-and-decision-trees-in)

If you want to explore a)...c), suggest something vaguely like this:

- exclude various subsets of the 10 continuous variables, then see which binary features show up as having the most gain. Let's say that gives you N candidate features. N will be << 90, let's assume N < 20 to make the following more computationally efficient.
- then compute the pairwise measure of association or correlation (Spearman or Kendall) between each of the N features. Look at a corrplot. Pick the clusters of variables which are most associated with each other. Create compound n-bit variables which combine those individual binary features. Then retrain the tree, including the compound variables, and excluding the individual binary variables (to avoid changing the total variance in the input).
- iterate for excluding various subsets of the 10 continuous variables. See which patterns emerge in your compound variables. I'm sure there's an algorithm for doing this (compound feature-engineering of n-bit categoricals) more formally and methodically, I just don't know it.
- Anyway, for hacking a tree-based method for better performance, I imagine the most naive way is "at every step, pick the two most highly-correlated/associated categorical features and combine them". Then retrain the tree (include new feature, exclude its constituent features) and use the revised gain numbers.
- perhaps a more robust way might be:

  - Pick some threshold T for correlation/association, say start at a high level T = 0.9 or 0.95
  - At each step, merge any features whose absolute correlation/association to each other >= T
  - If there were no merges at this step, reduce T by some value (like T -= 0.05) or ratio (e.g. T *= 0.9 . If still no merges, keep reducing T until there are merges, or until you hit some termination value (e.g. T = 0.03)
  - Retrain the tree including the compound variables, excluding their constituent subvariables.
  - Now go back and retrain what should be an improved tree with all 10 continuous variables, and your compound categorical features.
  - Or you could early-terminate the compound feature selection to see what the full retrained tree looks like.

This issue arose in the 2014 [Kaggle Allstate Purchase Prediction Challenge](https://www.kaggle.com/c/allstate-purchase-prediction-challenge/data), where the policy coverage options A,B,C,D,E,F,G were each categoricals with between 2-4 values, and very highly correlated with each other. (The current option of C, "C_previous", is one of the input features). See [that competitions's forums](https://www.kaggle.com/c/allstate-purchase-prediction-challenge/discussion) and published solutions for more. Be aware that policy = (A,B,C,D,E,F,G) is the output. But C_previous is an input variable.

Some general fast-and-dirty rules-of-thumb on feature selection from Kaggle are:

- throw out any near-constant/ very-low-variance variables (because they have near-zero information content)
- throw out any very-high-cardinality categorical variables (cardinality >~ training-set-size/2), (because they will also tend to have low information content, but cause lots of spurious overfitting and blow up training time). This can include customer IDs, row IDs, transaction IDs, sequence IDs, and other variables which shouldn't be trained on in the first place but accidentally ended up in the training set.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest few things for you to try.

1. Test your model without this data (only 90 features) and evaluate the decrease in your score. If it's insignificant you might want to remove those features.
2. Turn them into groups.
   For example, age can be categorized into groups, `0 : 0-7, 1 : 8-16, 2 : 17-25` and so on.
3. Turn them into binary. Out of the box idea on how to chose the best value to split them into binary is: Build 1 tree with 1 node (max depth = 1) and use only 1 feature. (1 out of the continuous features). then, dump the model to a .txt file and see the value it chose to split on. using this value, you can transform all that feature column into binary

I'm dealing myself with very similar problems right now, So i'll be happy to hear your results and the paths you chose to try.

Comment: *"2. Turn them into groups"* would be called binning, but the 90 variables are already categorical, they're not continuous. I don't see how binning the 10 continuous variables would change things.

Comment: *"3. dump the model to a .txt file and see the value it chose to split on."* No need to do that, just look at the *variable importance* or gain values. You can access it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I learned a lot from the answer by @smci, so I would recommend to follow his suggestions.

In the case, when your binary categorical features are in fact OHE representations of several categorical features with several classes in each, you can follow two more approaches:

- Convert OHE into label encoding. Yes, this has the caveat that one introduces an order into a categorical features, which might be meaningless, for example green=3 > red=2 > blue=1. But in practice is seems that trees handle label=encoded categorical variables (even with meaningless order) reasonably well.
- Convert OHE into target-/mean-/likelihood encoding. This is tricky, because you need to apply regularisation to avoid data leakage.

Both of those ideas are meant to group together several binary features into a single one based on prior knowledge about feature meaning. If you do not have that luxury, you can also try to deduce such groups by doing scalar product of columns and finding those giving zero product.

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming that "90 binary variables" genuinely means "90 distinct binary variables", not "One-Hot Encoding of between ~10-45 polychotomous categorical variables". If it's the latter, then we should combine those variables into their original categorical variables.